# I want to use a regular search method to filter / find users in my firebase database. But am clueless

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please I want to use a search on android and retrieve data like every normal search works... filter as the letters are typed. I have my data on Firebase database. "root - users - UniqueID - (name, class, age, ability). and I just want to find (filter) based on the ability. Am still fresh in firebase. Help me

Answer (score 1):

Firebase won't let you search on wildcards like a regular SQL type database will.

The best you can do with firebase is do a match on the start of the word.

An example for searching for the name "sketchthat".

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/users/')
  .orderByChild('name')
  .startAt('s')
  .endAt('t')
```

That will bring you all names starting with `s`.

You could refine it (example in Javascript)

```
var searchPhrase = 'sketch';
var searchEnd = searchPhrase.charCodeAt(searchPhrase.length - 1); // Gets the ASCII value.
var endAtPhrase = searchPhrase.substr(0, searchPhrase.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(searchEnd + 1); // Next character in the list "sketci"

firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/users/')
  .orderByChild('name')
  .startAt(searchPhrase)
  .endAt(endAtPhrase)
```

The problem with this solution is firebase is case-sensitive. So you'll need to have an uppercase or lowercase version of the name, then ensure all your searches are converted to that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
editext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String str = charSequence.toString();

            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("root").child("users");

            ref.orderByChild("name")
                    .startAt(str)
                    .endAt(str+"\uf8ff")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                               //get data
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```